# Notification/Broadcast when a Wi-Fi network is marked as metered

Tags: android

Users can designate Metered Wi-Fi networks in Settings -> Data usage -> Network restrictions.

[image]

Is there a way to be notified when the user changes a network between metered and un-metered? Would like my app to be notified if the active network has changed from metered to un-metered and vice versa, but being able to be notified of any user change on this screen would suffice.

It doesn't appear from my testing that `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` is fired.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to poll if you want this information in timely fashion. No broadcasts spotted in system or settings package code.